# How to overlay signature on UIImage with taking in consideration it's position?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiimage, digital-signature

I am working on a SwiftUI project in which I need to allow users to add their signatures to an image. Everything but adding the signature is working accordingly, so I'm seeking help here

My goal is to implement a feature that automatically detects the position of the user's signature in the image and then allows them to modify the image accordingly. Specifically, I would like to position my signature on the overlay in the image and add it over the image in what position it was.

EDIT: Imagine you have a sheet of paper. You are selecting a specific part of it and projecting your signature on it. That's what I'm trying to achieve.
EDIT2: iOS 15+

```
            GeometryReader { geometry in

                let magnificationGesture = MagnificationGesture()
                    .onChanged{ gesture in
                        scaleAnchor = .center
                        scale = lastScale * gesture
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        fixOffsetAndScale(geometry: geometry)
                    }
                
                let dragGesture = DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { gesture in
                        var newOffset = lastOffset
                        newOffset.width += gesture.translation.width
                        newOffset.height += gesture.translation.height
                        offset = newOffset
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        fixOffsetAndScale(geometry: geometry)
                    }
                                    
                Image(uiImage: scannedImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .border(.red, width: 2)
                    .position(x: geometry.size.width / 2,
                              y: geometry.size.height / 2)
                    .scaleEffect(scale, anchor: scaleAnchor)
                    .offset(offset)
                    .gesture(dragGesture)
                    .gesture(magnificationGesture)
                    .overlay (
                        VStack {
                            ZStack {
                                ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                                    
                                    Rectangle()
                                        .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2, dash: [5]))
                                        .fill(.blue)
                                        .opacity(opacity)
                                    
                                    Rectangle()
                                        .fill(.clear)
                                    
                                    Image(uiImage: choosenSignature)
                                        .resizable()
                                        .scaledToFit()
                                    
                                    VStack {
                                        HStack {
                                            Spacer()
                                            Circle()
                                                .fill(Color.green)
                                                .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                                                .onTapGesture {
                                                    
                                                    opacity = 0.0
//                                                    scale = 1.0
                                                    
                                                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3, execute: {
                                                        
                                                        // MARK: - Adding signature to image logic here
                                                        scannedImage = scannedImage
                                                        
                                                                                                                
                                                        opacity = 1.0
                                                    })
                                                }
                                        }
                                        Spacer()
                                    }
                                    .opacity(opacity)
                                    .zIndex(2)

                                    
                                    Circle()
                                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                                        .gesture(
                                            DragGesture()
                                                .onChanged { value in
                                                    // Enforce minimum dimensions.
                                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                                        withAnimation {
                                                            
                                                            width = max(50, width + value.translation.width / 10)
                                                            height = width
                                                            
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                        )
                                        .opacity(opacity)
                                        .zIndex(1)
                                    
                                }
                                .frame(width: width, height: height)
                                .rotationEffect(.degrees(knobRotation))
                                
                            }
                            
                        }
                            .frame(maxWidth: width, maxHeight: height, alignment: .center)
                            .position(location)
                            .gesture(
                                simpleDrag.simultaneously(with: fingerDrag)
                            )
                            .gesture(
                                RotationGesture()
                                    .onChanged { value in
                                        knobRotation = value.degrees
                                        print(knobRotation)
                                    }
                            )
                    )
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
            }
```

```
// FUNC FOR IMAGE OFFSET
    private func fixOffsetAndScale(geometry: GeometryProxy) {
        let newScale: CGFloat = .minimum(.maximum(scale, 1), 4)
        let screenSize = geometry.size

        let originalScale = scannedImage.size.width / scannedImage.size.height >= screenSize.width / screenSize.height ?
        geometry.size.width / scannedImage.size.width :
        geometry.size.height / scannedImage.size.height

        let imageWidth = (scannedImage.size.width * originalScale) * newScale

        var width: CGFloat = .zero
        if imageWidth > screenSize.width {
            let widthLimit: CGFloat = imageWidth > screenSize.width ?
            (imageWidth - screenSize.width) / 2
            : 0

            width = offset.width > 0 ?
                .minimum(widthLimit, offset.width) :
                .maximum(-widthLimit, offset.width)
        }

        let imageHeight = (scannedImage.size.height * originalScale) * newScale
        var height: CGFloat = .zero
        if imageHeight > screenSize.height {
            let heightLimit: CGFloat = imageHeight > screenSize.height ?
            (imageHeight - screenSize.height) / 2
            : 0

            height = offset.height > 0 ?
                .minimum(heightLimit, offset.height) :
                .maximum(-heightLimit, offset.height)
        }

        let newOffset = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        lastScale = newScale
        lastOffset = newOffset
        withAnimation() {
            offset = newOffset
            scale = newScale
        }
    }
```

I understand that I need to use image processing techniques for signature detection, but I'm not sure how to integrate this into my SwiftUI view. Can someone provide guidance or sample code on how to achieve this? Any help or pointers to relevant resources would be greatly appreciated.